# Neo4j - The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, neo4j, graphql, bolt

I'm currently running Neo4j version 3.4.9 on a Google Cloud VM instance and I'm having an authentication issue I can't resolve.

My Neo4j server is running fine in the cloud and I can access it directly using Neo4j browser. I have changed the default neo4j user password. I can also successfully query the Neo4j server from the GraphQL playground.

I've checked both the `neo4j-driver` and `neo4jgraphql-js` modules and they are both the latest versions. I have also checked my .env file and it has the correct username and password that matches the default `neo4j` user and the new password I changed to from the default.

I have tried running the Neo4j server without authentication by changing the `dbms.security.auth_enabled` setting to `false` in the `neo4j.conf` file but this hasn't helped.

I have also checked the Neo4j server logs and this is the error on the server side:

```
2020-07-21 17:59:48.830+0000 ERROR [o.n.b.t.TransportSelectionHandler] Fatal error occurred during protocol selection for connection: [id: 0x2434a10e, L:/10.154.0.2:7687 ! R:/86.151.231.207:63494] javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:459)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:392)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:359)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:342)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.channelInactive(SslHandler.java:1028)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:75)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1429)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:947)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:822)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:309)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:214)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1667)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1635)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1801)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1090)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:913)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:783)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:626)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$3.unwrap(SslHandler.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1275)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1177)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1221)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428)
```

This suggests a certificate error and so I have updated the `config_dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level` setting in the `neo4j.conf` file to `OPTIONAL` but I still get this error. I have also tried setting `config_dbms.connector.bolt.tls_level` to `DISABLED` but it doesn't solve the problem and creates lots of others!

One solution I have explored is setting up a certificate for the Neo4j server on GCP but according to this Neo4j guide [here](https://medium.com/neo4j/getting-certificates-for-neo4j-with-letsencrypt-a8d05c415bbd) you can only do that with a server that has a must have a valid DNS address, which mine doesn't. I didn't specify a hostname on creation and with GCP you can't add one retrospectively.

The only other solution I can think of is to build a fresh VM instance on GCP with a hostname, set up the correct DNS records, get the certificate and point my application at the new Neo4j server.

Comment: 1) To use SSL certificates your endpoint DNS name must match the certificate. You cannot (normally) use IP addresses. 2) Are you using a self-signed certificate?

Comment: I’m not using any certificate at the moment. Frustratingly my app was working fine without a certificate until a couple of days ago so I’m not sure why it needs one now.

Comment: Then why are you connecting using SSL/TLS? Use an HTTP endpoint or configure a certificate correctly.

Comment: I don’t know a lot about networking but GraphQL uses the bolt protocol which works over  a TCP connection so I don’t think it can be configured to work with HTTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the latest versions of `neo4j-driver` and `neo4jgraphql-js`, and yet you are running an old neo4j server version (3.4.9).

You may need to [upgrade](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/upgrade/) the neo4j server to the latest version.

Or, if you cannot do that, you can try using the latest JS packages that are compatible with neo4j 3.4.9. For example, `neo4j-driver` [version 1.7.7](https://www.npmjs.com/package/neo4j-driver/v/1.7.7) claims to be "for Neo4j 3.0.0+".